# References on equivalent characterization for Sobolev spaces of functions of one variable

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces

This is a question posted in MSE before-https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3169269/references-on-equivalent-characterization-for-sobolev-spaces-of-functions-of-one:

I cited a result which characterizes Sobolev spaces of functions of one variable as

> $ H^p(a,b):= \{ x \in C^{p-1} [a,b]:
>  x^{(p-1)}(t) = \alpha + \int^t_a \Psi ds, \ \alpha \in \mathbb{R}, \Psi \in L^2 \}$,
>
> where $ p \in \mathbb{N} $.

from page 14 of

> A. Kirsch: An Introduction to the Mathematical Theory of Inverse
>   Problems. Springer, New York, 1996.

However, the result in this monograph lacks details for proof. Could any researcher help with references with details?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your notation $H^k=W^{k,2}$, where $W^{k,p}$ represents the Sobolev space of functions whose derivatives of orders $\leq k$ are in $L^p$.

A function $f\in W^{1,p}(a,b)$ if and only if there is $g\in L^p(a,b)$ and a constant $\alpha$ such that  $f(x)=\alpha+\int_a^x g(t)\, dt$ for almost all $x\in (a,b)$. Since $f\in W^{k,p}(a,b)$ if and only if $f'\in W^{k-1,p}(a,b)$ your characterization follows.

For the proof of the above fact see Theorem 1 on p. 163 (in the first edition of the book) in the section Sobolev functions of one variable. You can find this book online.

**L. C. Evans, R. F. Gariepy**, *Measure theory and fine properties of functions.* Studies in Advanced Mathematics. CRC Press, Boca Raton, FL, 1992.

Comment: I can only describe part of my confuse: according to your notations, it seems that the characterization of version  C^{p-1} [a,b] lacks the almost everywhere equality. Moreover, in numerical analysis with Sobolev spaces H^{p}(a,b), it is a usual way to give restriction on evaluation at endpoint like x=a or b. It also seems contradicted to the almost everywhere definition you give here?

Comment: @YidongLuo Sobolev functions are defined almost everywhere by the definition and if you have a fucntion $W^{1,p}(a,b)$, then you can modify it on a set of measure zero so that it is continuous and equal to $f(x)=\alpha+\int_a^x g(t)\, dt$. Just take a book in Sobolev spaces and learn it. This is no place to ask such questions.

Comment: Get it and thank you for your tolerance.

Comment: But i still feel some confuse on the claim "Since $ f \in W^{k,p}(a,b) $ if and only if $ f' \in W^{k-1,p}(a,b) $ your characterization follows".  Firstly, i have no idea what $ f' $ denote for, almost everywhere or pointwise? Second, i always feel it lacks something to make $ f $ a classical function in $ C^{p-1} [a,b] $ automatically.  Sorry for my slow reacting.

Comment: All the derivatives should be viewed as weak derivatives. If a function is smooth enough, then the derivatives become the standard pointwise derivatives.

Comment: @ Deane Yang Thank you for explanations.

Comment: @ Piotr Hajlasz Now I can independently prove all results listed in question and answer. If it was not your help, I would not achieve this in one day. Thank you again and deeply!

Comment: @YidongLuo I am glad I could help.